# Can I find documents based on populate condition in mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I want to find those orders that customer first name like 'john'. want to use only mongo query.

I have a order collection like:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5669891a49b065ae2d7a5ea7"), 
    "customer" : ObjectId("563a399a11c9b15001565463"),
    "quantity" : "6"
}
```

my query:

```
var page = req.query.page || 1;
    var limit = req.query.limit || 20;
    var skip  = (page - 1) * limit;
var populateSearchQuery = { firstName: { '$regex': 'john', '$options': 'i' } }

Order.find({})
        .skip(skip).limit(limit)
        .populate('customer','firstName lastName', populateSearchQuery)
        .exec(function(error, orders) {
            if(error) {
                return res.status(400).send({msg: 'Error occurred while getting orders.'});
            }
        return res.status(200).send(orders);
        });
```

I got all orders but populate only matched condition customer. want only matched condition orders.

Is there any way to find only using mongo query?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible. You could get there with an [Aggregation Operation](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/aggregation/), but you'd still be getting all the docs and then sorting through them. Your best bet is probably just a 2 step query operation.

1. Get the ids for all the customers with a first name of john.
2. Get the orders that map to those customers.

```html
Customer.find({firstName: 'john'})
    .select('_id')
    .exec(function(err, customerDocs) {
        if (err) {...}
        var customerIds = [];
        for (var i=0; i<customerDocs.length; i++) {
            customerIds.push(customerDocs[i]._id);                                     
        }
        Order.find({customer: {$in: customerIds}})
             .exec(function(err, orderDocs) {...});
    });
```

Comment: Thanks your replay. It would be better for me if I could by mongoose query because I have  more fields this type.